# Python/Django looping over request object and display in a table

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Hi so I have a file called b2c2.py where I am making a request to return my balances this request returns `b'{"LTC":"0","DOG":"0","USD":"51075.676738623","ADA":"9493.1937","ETH":"3.4E-9","UST":"2977","LNK":"42.422","XLM":"0","GBP":"-58153.761361914","USC":"0.9999995","XRP":"78448.38","EOS":"0","BNB":"0","BTC":"-0.250000004644","EUR":"0.0026082","BCH":"0","DOT":"0","UNI":"0","AUD":"0","CAD":"0","CHF":"0","CNH":"0","ETC":"0","ICP":"0","JPY":"0","KSM":"0","MXN":"0","NZD":"0","SGD":"0","TRX":"0","XAU":"0","XMR":"0","XTZ":"0","ZEC":"0"}'`

I then store it into a variable named b2c2_response_content and import this into my view file with `from .api_balances.b2c2 import b2c2_response_content`

My view then looks like this:

```
  def b2c2(request):
    """ A view to return b2c2 page """
    context = {
        'b2c2_reponse_content': b2c2_reponse_content,
    }
    return render(request, 'home/b2c2.html', context)
```

As you can see it is now passed into my context. What I need it to do is in my actual .html file show the values for example BTC (bitcoin) in one column with its balance in the column next to it and then the row below to show the next balance for example ETH(Ethereum) with its balance next to it.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is your passing context,
you can render it into html template using jinja format as follows:

```
<table>
   <tr>
     <th>Balance Name</th>
     <th>Balance Holding</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    {% for name, holding in b2c2_reponse_content.items %}
     <td>{{name}}</td>
     <td>{{holding}}</td>
   </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Comment: Hey, so this code is not showing anything on my page I updated my question a little to better show you what my code looks like

Comment: use b2c2_reponse_content instead of context..

Comment: Yeah so I changed it to that but still nothing returned

Comment: there is a 'b' before dictionary? is it a byte object?

Comment: No, from what I can see the b is being returned from the API so maybe stands for bal

Comment: try beore putting b2c2_reponse_content into context
**
import json
json.loads(b2c2_reponse_content.decode('utf-8'))
**